# Generating random numbers including negative ones vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I'm currently working on a uni project(vhdl) and i need some code that helps me generating random numbers from a range like -32,+32.

I did find some code but it only generates from 0 to 32 because i don't know how i could've manage to generate negative ones.

```
entity rand_gen is
end rand_gen;

architecture behavior of rand_gen is 

signal rand_num : integer := 0;

begin

process
    variable seed1, seed2: positive;              
    variable rand: real;  
    variable range_of_rand : real := 32.0;   
begin
    uniform(seed1, seed2, rand); 
    rand_num <= integer(rand*range_of_rand);  
    wait for 10 ns;
end process;
```

Comment: Why not change the range and offset by 32? range_of_rand := 64;   rand_num <= integer(rand*range_of_rand) -32;

Comment: It won't work after the first simulation. It will set -32 for the first time then will go into the 0-64 range.